# evaluating Boolean operation in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I’m solving this question:

Create a `String` variable called `currentLightColor` and set its value to `"Green"`, `"Yellow"`, or `"Red"`.
Create conditional `if` / `else if` / `else` logic to print: `"The light is X"` where X is the value of the light variable. The `if` / `else if` / `else` clause should print the appropriate color.

I have tried the code below but it is not working out well for me

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var currentLightColor = "green"; "yellow"; "Red"
    if (currentLightColor == "green") {
        println("the light is green")
    } else if (currentLightColor == "yellow") {
        println("the light is yellow")
    } else {
        println("The light is Red")
    }
}
```

Can anyone solve this please?

Comment: You do not need an _if...else_ clause, string interpolation will do. You only need one line instead: _println("the light is $currentLightColor")_

Comment: what you mean by `it is not working out well for me` ? Are you seeing any error? what is the output?

Comment: @lukas.j OP definitely does not *need* a conditional structure, but it seems he *has* to use one. I'm just wondering if a `when` is acceptable instead of `if`-`else`…

Comment: Do you know how to reference a `var`/`val` in a `String`, @davidokoth?

Comment: Is it possible this example  *is not working out well for* you because it only prints `"the light is green"` ignoring the other values? If yes, that's what kotlin does with valid `String` values that are not bound to any `var` or `val`, it simply ignores them. Build up a `List` or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* do that without any conditional logic, just using a reference to the variable in the `String` to be printed:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // example list of all valid lights
    var lightColors = listOf("green", "yellow", "red")
    // print the same sentence for each value
    lightColors.forEach { println("the light is $it") }
}
```

Output:

```
the light is green
the light is yellow
the light is red
```

The problem here is you cannot react to an invalid value (e.g. `"blue"`).

Either use the answer by @Twistleton (maybe reference the variable instead of hard-coding the `String` to be printed), or use your current one with the reference to the variable, maybe like this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var currentLightColor = "blue";
    if (currentLightColor == "green") {
        println("the light is $currentLightColor")
    } else if(currentLightColor == "yellow") {
        println("the light is $currentLightColor")
    } else if (currentLightColor == "red") {
        println("the light is $currentLightColor")
    } else {
        println("unknown color $currentLightColor")
    }
}
```

Output here:

```
unknown color blue
```

As you can see in the second example, you would only need conditional logic if you are expecting invalid colors. Otherwise, the simple first example should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a when-structure if that is allowed:

```
var currentLightColor = "green"

when (currentLightColor) {
  "green" -> println("the light is green")
  "yellow" -> println("the light is yellow")
  "red" -> println("the light is red")
  else -> println("unknown light")
}
```